# Unable to save custom registration field value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration, account

I've really got frustrated, I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-woocommerce-registration-form-fields/) to add custom field to my WooCommerce registration form. But annoyingly enough I have not been able to do so.

I've written this code to achieve this:

```
function woocom_extra_register_fields() {?>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="company_name" id="company_name" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Company Name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>*" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['company_name'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['company_name'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
    </p>
<?php

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'woocom_extra_register_fields' );


function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['company_name'])) {
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'company_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['company_name']));
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );
```

The hook is not working and I don't know why. I'll really appreciate the help.